# Second conditional Sentences

Tags: conditionals

Second conditional has always been a matter of confusion for me , can it be used while referring to a past condition , I know third conditional is used while referring to a past condition but still i have seen second conditional being used while referring to past

Comment: I think you will need to provide some examples of the sorts of sentences you mean.

Comment: for example - " You wouldn't be here if you tried to save her " what does this imply ?

Comment: @Archit It would be more natural (if not in fact necessary, in a strict sense) to say *You wouldn't be here if you **had** tried to save her*. You should add that to your question, and also add why the sentence is confusing. Note that most native English speakers do not classify conditionals into categories. The concept is imprecise, and the few used are incomplete.

Comment: I agree with you , it sounds much more appropriate